# Some checkboxes' value is treated as if it were FALSE even though it is TRUE

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few checkboxes in my worksheet (around 120) and I have been using this code on each of them:

```vb
Private Sub Food_Click()
    Static isBusy As Boolean
    Dim FoodC As String

    If Not isBusy Then
        isBusy = True
        
        FoodC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Checkbox Formulas").Range("k7").Value
        If FoodC = False Then
            Food.Value = False
            MsgBox "You Are Missing Ingredients", vbCritical, "Missing Ingredients"
        End If
        
        isBusy = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Each checkbox has its own name.

The problem is that in some checkboxes (6 checkboxes out of 120) the value of the variable is `TRUE`, but when I click on them it returns the MsgBox as if the value were `FALSE` (the code is working backwards). When I debug the code it says it's working correctly.

I have tested to assign the value of the cell of another checkbox that works fine in the checkbox working incorrectly and then it works fine. So I'm assuming the problem is with the cell.

The value of the cell (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) is given by an Excel formula in the worksheet.

Comment: Is`hisWorkbook.Sheets("Checkbox Formulas").Range("k7").Value` somehow changed according to the clicked check box value? Everything is evaluated according to its value.

Comment: The value of the cell doesn't change when the checkbox is clicked. Plus the only way the checkbox can be clicked is if the variable is equal `true`, Other way, it should returned the MsgBox when you try to click it. If the value of the cell is `true`, the variable stays `true` even if you click the checkbox or not. The only thing that can change the variable value is the excel formula, which has nothing to do with the checkbox

Comment: If the code is the same, I mean, targeting the same `Range("k7")`, independent of any check box value, if it is `False` the message box will show up.  What "the code is working backwards" does mean? How do you "debug" the code and "it says it's working correctly"?

Comment: Every checkbox targets its specific cell... The code is supposed to show a MsgBox and return the checkbox to `false`when a specific cell is `false`. Each checkbox checks a different and unique cell value. When I say "It's working backwards", I mean the cell is `true`, but the when I try to click the checkbox it's showing the MsgBox and returning the checkbox to `false` (This doesn't happen in every checkbox, only in 6 checkboxes, the others are working fine)...When I debug the code in these 6 checkboxes it goes to every step correctly as it's supposed to

Comment: Do you mean that in case of the 6 different check boxes, the "specific cell"  is `True` and message is showing up? Did you check the code line by line, pressing F8 and check the cell value? It is obvious that it is false and the problem should not be searched in the code itself, I think.

Comment: I found the error. In those cases after I clicked the checkbox the cell they are referencing to changes to `false`. So I need a line that stop checking it after I click it